# Change Textbox to Label in WPF

Tags: wpf

How can I change all `TextBox`es to `Label`s when a button is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

You would be better setting them all to disabled (`IsEnabled = false`) or read only (`IsReadOnly = true`), and changing the `TextBox` style to suit your needs.

There are some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041512/prevent-a-readonly-textbox-from-being-grayed-out-in-silverlight) for changing the style of a `TextBox`.

Comment: Agree. Depending on what @Joby wants to do, it might also be sufficient if just the `IsReadOnly` property is set to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do as @devdigital said, which is a correct solution. What you also could do is set the IsReadOnly property to true. This way you achieve the same as when disabling the TextBox, but instead you don't get an ugly grayed-out one where you cannot select the Text/Content from the TextBox.